Unable to install iohook in my node server (error during installation)
I'm trying to add the ability to detect keypress anywhere on my PC, and I saw about iohook.
So I'm installing it with yarn add iohook, though the process always fails because the download link seems missing (404 error)
This is the first time it happens to me during the installation of a module, so I have no idea what I'm supposed to do... Thank you a lot for your help.
Here are the logs:
yarn add v1.22.22
warning ..\package.json: No license field
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning iohook > nugget > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning iohook > nugget > request > har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
warning iohook > nugget > request > uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
error D:\Documents\WebStorm projects\Twitch bot\TwitchNode\node_modules\iohook: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node install.js
Arguments:
Directory: D:\Documents\WebStorm projects\Twitch bot\TwitchNode\node_modules\iohook
Output:
Downloading prebuild for platform: iohook-v0.9.3-node-v115-win32-x64
Downloading prebuild.tar.gz
Error: GET https://github.com/wilix-team/iohook/releases/download/v0.9.3/iohook-v0.9.3-node-v115-win32-x64.tar.gz returned 404
Prebuild for current platform (iohook-v0.9.3-node-v115-win32-x64) not found!
Try to build for your platform manually:
# cd node_modules/iohook;
# npm run build

D:\Documents\WebStorm projects\Twitch bot\TwitchNode\node_modules\iohook\install.js:16
  throw err;
  ^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\DRAKEM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\prebuild.tar.gz'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\DRAKEM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\prebuild.tar.gz'
}

Node.js v20.12.2
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

